# How do I cut 2 parts of 2 diffrent objects?

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, blender-internal-render-engine

I'm new in Blender.

I want to cut the 2 parts of 2 diffrent objects as I showed in the picture. But I just want to cut these 2 parts,which they're in the red circle.

Thank you so much...

[image]

Comment: Do u want to slice that part or difference

Comment: Difference.....

Comment: join both with ctrl+j and then with boolean difference

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked :)